# what kind of components can fail in rmi?

Tags: process, components, rmi

Was wondering what kind of software and hardware component cant fail in a rmi program?

so for example in a client server model when a client invokes an object in the server?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick list of RMI related failures:

- Networking related failures.  This list is rather large.  If this is Java and windows, watch out for DNS related problems.  I've seen some rather nasty challenges on large corporate LANs.
- Version control between client and server
- I've seen scaling problems with Java RMI and the default ServerSocket handler.

In general, I'm not a big fan of Java RMI.  While it takes care of some problems, its implementation in traditional enterprise networks have caused me more problems than it saves.  There usually are other choices out there.